# Laravel Mix return error on windows 10

Tags: laravel, webpack

I'm using latest [Laravel Mix](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix) to compile my JS file.

But every time I run npm run dev (scripts come from Laravel package.json) it always return me an error (If something fail when compile) but never show me what exactly went wrong.

[image: Error]

Never happen when using laravel elixir.

Here is the package.json script:

```
"scripts": {
"dev": "node node_modules/cross-env/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
"watch": "node node_modules/cross-env/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
"hot": "node node_modules/cross-env/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
"production": "node node_modules/cross-env/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
},
```

Any solution?

Comment: Have you updated? Jeffrey tagged a new release 12 hours ago. It may fix your problem

Comment: @AndyHolmes I already update my laravel mix to 0.6.0 (latest right now) still no luck

Comment: Ah that's a shame. He's active on the repo at the minute, if you get no luck here it's probably worth putting an issue in - https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/issues

Comment: Does this help at all? - https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/issues/165
I'm on a mac environment so can't help too much I'm afraid :/

Comment: @AndyHolmes I'm build react project. right now I can solve the compile react project using .babelrc with react preset. for other error, seems like few users still experiencing the issue

Answer (score 0):

it happens the same for me, but it was a lag on connection, and a package didn't installed correctly, I'd just deleted the `node_modules` directory and `npm install` again, problem solve for me.